# "Object reference not set to an instace of an object" error while using oauth in Microsoft BotFramework-Composer

Tags: oauth, botframework, bot-framework-composer

I am using Microsoft BotFramework Composer and adding Oauth through AzureAD, I'm able to successfully login and generate token but as soon as the login step is over, I get an output
`Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Can anybody tell me what's wrong here, I tried to do the same step in a complete new project but the output remains the same.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please have a look at the handy guide to see the steps you can take to get a better answer faster: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Can you provide some repro steps? Are you following any documentation or tutorials? Can you link to them?

Comment: I've followed this documentation to add [OAuth in Bot Composer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/how-to-use-oauth). I'm able to generate token though. To reproduce add a Oauth step to your Bot in Bot Composer and run it in Bot Framework Emulator

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem, so it must necessarily be caused by something you haven't told us about. OAuth works fine for me and I get no errors. If you would like Stack Overflow to be able to help you with your problem, you will need to provide more information. Did you read the help document I linked to?